# Stop an NSTimer In A UIPopover

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nstimer

So I have a UIPopover with an NSTimer in it.  It has various BOOLS and properties to make other methods happen, but that's not important right now.  What I want to know is, is there any way to release and invalidate the timer when the parent view of the popover has disappeared?  I tried class methods to invalidate and release the timer, but they gave me SIGABRT and EXC_BAD_ACCESS warnings.  I think it had something to do with the timer being to told to dealloc when it was already nil.

A couple extra factors:
1. The timer must stay valid and alloc'd when the popover is dismissed.
2. The timer must invalidate and dealloc when the parent view has disappeared.

Any suggestions?

CODE:

```
//@interface
    NSTimer *clickTimer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *clickTimer;

//.m
- (IBAction)clickerPressed:(id)sender
{
if ([click isClicking] == YES) {
    [clickTimer invalidate];
    [clickTimer release];
    clickTimer = nil;
    // enable the idle timer when the clicking is turned off
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
    [click setIsClicking:NO];
    [clickerButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clickerButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clickStatus setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[click numberOfBeatsToDisplay]]];
    [click setClickCount:0];

} 
else {
    // disable the idle timer while the metronome is clicking.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
    [click setIsClicking:YES];
    [clickerButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clickerButton setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[NSThread currentThread] setThreadPriority:1.0];

    clickTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[click clickRateInSeconds] target:self selector:@selector(click:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]retain];
    }
```

}

Comment: Always, Always when releasing a variable outside of dealloc set it to nil. `[clickTimer release]; clickTimer = nil;`

Comment: Edited, sorry <facepalm>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Releasing an object does not automatically assign nil to the pointer.  Add `clickTimer = nil;` after your release statement.  This will prevent another method from accessing an invalid object if it attempts to release *clickTimer*.

To ensure that all of your methods properly set the *clickTimer* to *nil*, you might consider creating a method that invalidates the timer for you rather than having each method invalidate the timer:

```
- (void) invalidateClickTimer
{
    // invalidate timer
    if (clickTimer == nil)
        return;
    [clickTimer invalidate];
    [clickTimer release];
    clickTimer = nil;

    // stop clicking
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
    [click setIsClicking:NO];
    [clickerButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clickerButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clickStatus setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[click numberOfBeatsToDisplay]]];
    [click setClickCount:0];
    return;
}
```

Then replace the following lines in `- (IBAction)clickerPressed:(id)sender`

```
if ([click isClicking] == YES) {
    [clickTimer invalidate];
    [clickTimer release];
    clickTimer = nil;
    // enable the idle timer when the clicking is turned off
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
    [click setIsClicking:NO];
    [clickerButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clickerButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clickStatus setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[click numberOfBeatsToDisplay]]];
    [click setClickCount:0];
}
```

With this line:

```
if ([click isClicking] == YES) {
    [self invalidateClickTimer];
}
```

Call the new method `- (void) invalidateClickTimer` from the parent view's UIViewController.  Probably in the method `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: Nope, no dice.  The timer is invalidated and made nil by your method, but it won't stop clicking

Comment: The timer is the BPM of a metronome I've made.  It appears in a popover.  Your method invalidates the timer, but the clicks continue.

Comment: Ah, does the code following `// enable the idle timer when the clicking is turned off` invalidate the clicking?

Comment: Yes.  It's connected to a button.  The button shows either "Start" or "stop" depending on if it's clicked.  I put NSLog's around your code.  It releases the timer beautifully, but the clicking keeps chugging away.

Comment: Tried your update.  Still clicking away.  This is really annoying.  I must be doing something wrong, but there's no errors or memory leaks.

Comment: How are you invalidating the timer when your view is unloaded?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4099/discussion-between-david-m-syzdek-and-codafi)